# Populate data from DB and save as new record oracle forms

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

I Have populated master detail block from Data based want to change some values in data block and save it as a new record in Both master and child tables.

To Populate used execute query
Changed values as record
Save by commit

But as i used execute query to populate existing data on commit it is trying to update already saved data in table. But i want to create new records in DB with new primary key

Answer (score 0):

That won't work, as you noticed. Records you fetched are **database records** so - once you update their values and commit, you **overwrite** data.

If you want to **insert** new records, then

- add them into new rows - you can do that manually (by typing those values), or
- you can **duplicate** one of previous records into a new record (use Forms menu for that or a shortcut key; look for "duplicate record" option) and modify that *duplicated* record.

Alternatively, don't use data block but **control block** (the one that isn't based on a database table). Populate it, somehow (e.g. you could create a button which calls the procedure; it uses a loop and populates record-by-record). Modify values you want and create your own procedure which will insert new rows into the database table. As of the primary key, it depends on how you do it; if it is a database trigger which uses a sequence, it (the trigger) will do the job. Otherwise, you'll have to create a primary key yourself (during the insert process).

Comment: is this possible to duplicate record using my own code. I actually have 3 blocks of almost 250 fields of database not possible to create control block

Comment: I guess it is; when you write your own procedure, you're the "boss" and can do *anything* you want. Won't look pretty, though ... 250 fields is quite a lot to handle.